# Firefox addon compatibility error

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm trying to build a simple XUL addon for Firefox. I don't use any tools for building it. The build process is as follows: compress the project file into a .zip, then rename the .zip into an .xpi file, go to Firefox addon manager and use "Install Add-ons From File..." but then I get the error "Add-on could not be installed because it is not compatible with Firefox 33.1.1".
This is my install.rdf file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" mlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
<Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
<em:id>addon@addon.com</em:id>
<em:type>2</em:type>
<em:name>addon</em:name>
<em:version>1.0</em:version>
<em:creator>SC</em:creator>
<em:description>addon description</em:description>
<em:homepageURL>http://www.example.com/</em:homepageURL>
<em:iconURL>chrome://addon/skin/icon.png</em:iconURL>
<em:optionsURL>chrome://addon/content/options.xul</em:optionsURL>
<em:targetApplication>
  <Description>
    <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3bbe97384}</em:id> <!-- Firefox -->
    <em:minVersion>29.*</em:minVersion>
    <em:maxVersion>36.*</em:maxVersion>
  </Description>
</em:targetApplication>
</Description>
</RDF>
```

I tried with various min and max versions but I am getting the same error. I have the feeling that the problem lies elsewhere and not in the minVersion and maxVersion from this file.
Where else could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GUID, `<em:id>`, you are using is incorrect for Firefox.  For desktop Firefox you should use:

```
<em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
```

The difference is in the last section.
Incorrect: 
`13a3bbe97384`
 
Correct:
`13a3a9e97384`

You can find a list of valid GUIDs and versions on the Mozilla [Valid Application Versions](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/pages/appversions/) page.

While it is not causing your error, you probably don't want to be using:
`<em:minVersion>29.*</em:minVersion>`
Wildcards should not be used in the `<em:minVersion>` field.  The wildcard will default to the highest possible version.  For what you are probably wanting – all versions that are 29 or higher – you should use:
`<em:minVersion>29.0</em:minVersion>`

Specifically, see [Choosing minVersion and maxVersion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extension_Versioning,_Update_and_Compatibility#Choosing_minVersion_and_maxVersion):

> Do not mistakenly think that * in a version represents any version. The * actually represents an infinitely high number and so is really only sensibly used in the maxVersion. Using it in a minVersion usually doesn't produce the effect you want.

Comment: Wow very attentive of you!